# htaccess redirect based on directories and subdirectories

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i have a special situation and i can't find a good solution. I've already seen dozens of questions/answers here but none of them seems to solve my problem!

I have an url like this: 
`https://subdomain.domain.com/{user-name}/{app-name}/`

"user-name" and "app-name" can change everytime and i need to redirect it to 
`index.php?u={user-name}&a={app-name}`

But if the url is only `https://subdomain.domain.com/{user-name}/` i need to redirect it to 
`store-list.php?u={user-name}` (to show a list of all available apps for that user).

My .htaccess is currently like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /store-list.php?u=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?u=$1&a=$2 [L]
```

It redirects perfectly on both situations but every call to a "real" file doesn't work (for example a call to a js or css file inside my html).

What am i doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Making one RewriteCond Set Apply to Several Rules**

Yes, we're really close... but a RewriteCond only applies to one rule. That's what is throwing us off. Let's use some tricky logic and put the conditions in reverse:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^ - [L,S=2]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /store-list.php?u=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?u=$1&a=$2 [L]
```

The conditions say that if the files **do** exist, leave them unchanged, and to skip the two next rules (`S=2`).

Comment: +1 this should work and `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` isn't even needed.

Comment: @anubhava `^index\.php$ - [L] isn't even needed` Nicely spotted, a leftover from copy-pasting. Thanks for your encouragements, hope it works for Dario. :)

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work. I get a 404 error with `The requested URL /dc-design/dario-store/ was not found on this server.`

Comment: Looks like I had one extra `OR` (second cond), can you try again?

Comment: Since you have `L` you can remove `S=2` also.

Comment: @anubhava Do you trust `L` in a directory context?

Comment: Yes absolutely I trust use of `L` here.

Comment: yeah it works! also without `S=2` like @anubhava suggested! Many thanks guys!!

Comment: Wow, terrific! Thanks Dario, see you next time. :)

Comment: @anubhava Thanks heaps for the teamwork! See you next time. :)